# Is there an $L<1$ such that $\left\Vert f(z_1) -f(z_2) \right\Vert_2 \leq L \left\Vert z_1 -z_2 \right\Vert_2 $

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $f(x,y)=(\sqrt{4-y^2},\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}})$. I'm trying to show if there exists an $L<1$ such that
>
> $\left\Vert f(z_1) -f(z_2) \right\Vert_2 \leq L \left\Vert z_1 -z_2 \right\Vert_2 $ for all $z_1,z_2 \in S=\{0,2\} \times \{0,2\}$.

I'm stuck, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that if such an $L$ were to exist it would provide a bound on the Jacobian matrix. Now consider the Jacobian close to $y=2$.

Comment: Yep, realized that it doesnt work for that domain. I know how to solve it now. Apparently this question is off topic and it got downvoted so ill delete it later

Comment: It would be sufficient to add context. It seems that you are looking for fixed points of $f$ and need to choose a smaller domain like $[1,2]\times[0,1]$ to apply the fixed-point theorem.

Comment: Thats my aim indeed. Thank you